# I create a table with a foreign key from table TABLE4_PRC; I get this error: ORA-00907

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle. I try to create a table, but I get this error `ORA-00907`.

This is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE table11_prc 
(
    Family  VARCHAR2(200),
    Name    VARCHAR2(200),
    ID      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TABLE_PRC4(id)
);
```

Comment: You haven't specified the data type for the `name_id` column; and if you're declaring the column and the FK at the same time then you shouldn't have the `foreign key` keywords. You're mixing up the syntax from different approaches.

Comment: @AlexPoole Datatype is optional for FK-constrained column. *[In general, you must specify datatype. However, the following exceptions apply](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6): ... You can also omit datatype if the statement designates the column as part of a foreign key in a referential integrity constraint. Oracle Database automatically assigns to the column the data type of the corresponding column of the referenced key of the referential integrity constraint.*

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_prc4
  2  (
  3     id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table11_prc
  2  (
  3     family    VARCHAR2 (200),
  4     name      VARCHAR2 (200),
  5     id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  6     name_id   INTEGER REFERENCES table_prc4 (id)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

(or any of its alternatives, as you can create inline or out-of-line constraints, specify some more info (or even less), but ... that's it).